# Dúvidas sobre relacionamento e mapeamento com Fluent API para o EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Sempre que eu tiver uma classe com propriedades que são do tipo de outras classes, o que a nível de banco de dados representa uma chave estrangeira, eu sempre vou precisar das propriedades de navegação?

E vejam este exemplo:

`Revenda -> ClienteRevenda -> Empresa -> ClienteEmpresa`

```c-sharp
public class Revenda
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    // Navigation Property
    public ICollection<ClienteRevenda> Clientes {get; set;}
}

public class ClienteRevenda
{
    [Key, Column(0)]
    public int RevendaId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId")]
    public Empresa Empresa {get; set;}

    [Key, Column(1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    // Navigation Property
    public ICollection<Empresa> Empresas {get; set;}
}

public class Empresa
{
    [Key, Column(0)]
    public int RevendaId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId")]
    public Revenda Revenda {get; set;}

    [Key, Column(1)]
    public int ClienteRevendaId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId, ClienteRevendaId")]
    public ClienteRevenda ClienteRevenda {get; set;}

    [Key, Column(2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    // Navigation Property
    public ICollection<ClienteEmpresa> ClientesEmpresa {get; set;}
}

public class ClienteEmpresa
{
    [Key, Column(0)]
    public int RevendaId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId")]
    public Revenda Revenda {get; set;}

    [Key, Column(1)]
    public int ClienteRevendaId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId, ClienteRevendaId")]
    public ClienteRevenda ClienteRevenda {get; set;}

    [Key, Column(2)]
    public int EmpresaId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId, ClienteRevendaId, EmpresaId")]
    public Empresa Empresa {get; set;}

    [Key, Column(3)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
}
```

Notem que estou fazendo chaves compostas porque preciso de registros únicos.
Nesse caso, eu precisaria adicionar na classe Revenda as Navigation Properties para `Empresa` e `ClienteEmpresa` também?

Como ficaria esse mapeamento com a **Fluent API**?

```c-sharp
public class RevendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Revenda>
{
    public RevendaMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class ClienteRevendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClienteRevenda>
{
    public ClienteRevendaMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => new { p.RevendaId, p.Id });
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasRequired(p => p.Revenda).WithMany(r => r.Clientes).HasForeignKey(p => p.RevendaId);
    }
}

public class EmpresaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Empresa>
{
    public EmpresaMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => new { p.RevendaId, p.ClienteRevendaId, p.Id });
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasRequired(p => p.Revenda).WithMany( ??? ).HasForeignKey(p => p.RevendaId);
        HasRequired(p => p.ClienteRevenda).WithMany(cr => cr.Empresas).HasForeignKey(p => p.ClienteRevendaId);
    }
}

public class ClienteEmpresaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClienteEmpresa>
{
    public ClienteEmpresaMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => new { p.RevendaId, p.ClienteRevendaId, p.EmpresaId, p.Id });
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasRequired(p => p.Revenda).WithMany( ??? ).HasForeignKey(p => p.RevendaId);
        HasRequired(p => p.ClienteRevenda).WithMany( ??? ).HasForeignKey(p => p.ClienteRevendaId);
        HasRequired(p => p.Empresa).WithMany(e => e.ClientesEmpresa).HasForeignKey(p => p.EmpresaId);
    }
}
```

Notem nas duas últimas classes de mapeamento que elas possuem o método `WithMany( ??? )`. Minha pergunta se a classe `Revenda` deveria ter uma *navigation property* para cada uma das outras classes e também perguntando por conta dessas outras classes e esses métodos. O que deveria ser informado neles?

Ou é a estrutura de classes que está errada, ou o mapeamento que está errado...?

Comment: A idéia seria ter chaves compostas?

Comment: Sim, pela estrutura/segurança dos dados, certo?

Comment: Eu até perguntei se essa era uma forma certa de escrever o modelo. Não sei, talvez não seria necessário fazer chaves compostas, mas deixar apenas o **Id** de cada classe como chave primária, o restante fazer apenas chave estrangeira obrigatória.. mas é sobre as regras de mapeamento para o EF que mais tenho dúvida.

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta e explicar o porque daquele relacionamento? Pq se fosse pra fazer a chave composta, poderia fazer por fluent assim: `modelBuilder.Entity<Revenda>().HasKey(r => new { r.RevendaId, r.Id });`

Comment: A questão maior não é as chaves, eu posso até remover as chaves. As chaves eu coloquei para complicar ainda mais a questão da necessidade das propriedades de navegação. Porque, já que há inserção de propriedade da primeira classe na última, aumentou a necessidade de propriedades de navegação. Então, a questão é se eu preciso sair inserindo propriedade de navegação de todas as camadas? Como exemplo, se eu preciso inserir `ICollection<ClienteEmpresa>` na classe `Revenda` ?

Comment: Não não... Por exemplo... quem vai ter propriedade de navegação de `ClienteEmpresa` vai ser somente empresa

Comment: Isso que eu queria saber, que inclusive foi algo que o @CiganoMorrisonMendez achou estranho na minha pergunta anterior. Porque já que minha classe `Revenda` não tem propriedade de navegação para a classe `ClienteEmpresa`, logo, na minha classe `ClienteRevendaMap` essa atribuição `HasRequired(p => p.Revenda).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.RevendaId);` estaria correta, certo???

Comment: Não entendi o relaciomento entre as entidades. Uma `Revenda` tem n `ClienteEmpresa`? Uma empresa tem n `ClienteEmpresa`? Uma `Empresa` tem n `ClienteEmpresa`?

Comment: Então @CiganoMorrisonMendez, meu problema era aprender sobre como montar os relacionamentos para o EF, principalmente sobre propriedades de navegação para o correto entendimento do EF. E o exemplo que montei criou toda esse nó por conta das chaves primárias compostas, de onde eu quis saber então se por conta da existência dessas chaves eu precisaria sair incluindo propriedade de navegação desde a primeira classe, a de `Revenda`.

Comment: @Tiago Tá bem errada sua abordagem. Eu estou tentando escrever uma resposta, mas não entendi o relacionamento entre as entidades.

Comment: Deixa eu tentar trazer para um exemplo real. Eu desenvolvo softwares, minhas revendas possuem Clientes ( `ClienteRevenda` , distribuidoras, por exemplo ), e esses clientes atendem outras empresas ( `Empresa` , varejo). Empresas essas que possuem seus clientes ( `ClienteEmpresa` , cliente final). Botando isso num sistema que engloba tudo, por exemplo, eu já começaria por ter várias revendas em minha base de dados, logo fiz a separação de Clientes das Revendas, Empresas e Clientes das Empresas forçando a integridade dos dados com campos de chaves compostas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A co-relação entre as properties deveria ser algo da seguinte maneira

```
//Revenda
public ICollection<ClienteRevenda> { get; set; }  //Navigation para os ClientesRevendas que possui

//ClienteRevenda
public Revenda Revenda { get; set; } //Navigation para a superior(que pertence)
public ICollection<Empresa> { get; set; }

//Empresa
public ClienteRevenda ClienteRevenda { get; set; } //Navigation para a superior
public ICollection<ClienteEmpresa> { get; set; }

//ClienteEmpresa
public Empresa Empresa{ get; set; } //Navigation para a superior
```

Comment: Ok, isso já me esclareceu 50% de minhas dúvidas. ;)

Comment: Como boas práticas para o EF, chaves compostas dessa forma como montei e o que você mostrou ser o ideal já não é bom. Correto? Você não incluiu propriedade **navigation para a superior** como eu fiz por contas das chaves compostas.

Answer (score 2):

### Chaves Compostas

A ideia em nada melhora a segurança ou estrutura, dificultando inclusive a implementação dos seus *Controllers* e *Views*. Basta uma *property* como chave primária que as demais Id's são acessíveis através das classes virtuais declaradas. Este uso pode até ser considerado uma má prática.

### Modelagem das Entidades

```
public class Revenda
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Nome {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ClienteRevenda> Clientes {get; set;}
}

public class ClienteRevenda
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int RevendaId {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string Nome {get; set;}

    public virtual Revenda Revenda {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Empresa> Empresas {get; set;}
}

public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ClienteRevendaId {get; set;}

    [Required]    
    public string Nome {get; set;}

    public virtual ClienteRevenda ClienteRevenda {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ClienteEmpresa> ClientesEmpresa {get; set;}
}

public class ClienteEmpresa
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int EmpresaId {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string Nome {get; set;}

    public virtual Empresa Empresa {get; set;}
}
```

### Mapeamentos

```
public class RevendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Revenda>
{
    public RevendaMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class ClienteRevendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClienteRevenda>
{
    public ClienteRevendaMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasRequired(p => p.Revenda).WithMany(r => r.Clientes).HasForeignKey(p => p.RevendaId);
    }
}

public class EmpresaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Empresa>
{
    public EmpresaMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasRequired(p => p.ClienteRevenda).WithMany(cr => cr.Empresas).HasForeignKey(p => p.ClienteRevendaId);
    }
}

public class ClienteEmpresaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClienteEmpresa>
{
    public ClienteEmpresaMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => new p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasRequired(p => p.Empresa).WithMany(e => e.ClientesEmpresa).HasForeignKey(p => p.EmpresaId);
    }
}
```

Comment: No caso ainda os Key, Colunm podem ser removidos

Comment: Já editei. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

@Tiago não tem a ver com a resposta em si da perguntar, mas sim em outro pronto que você deve se atentar a isso, é a maneira como irá trabalhar o load dessas dependencias...

Por exemplo, caso você precise acessar o primeiro `ClienteEmpresa` da sua primeira `Empresa` da sua primeira `ClienteRevenda` da sua `Revenda` dentro um laço foreach, seria algo mais ou menos assim (da maneira digamos mais comum de fazer).

```
foreach(var item in ctx.Revendas) {
    var nome = item.Revenda
    .ClienteRevendas().FirstOrDefault()
    .Empresas().FirstOrDefault()
    .ClienteEmpresas().FirstOrDefault().Nome;
    //faz alguma coisa por exemplo
}
```

Dependendo da maneira como for carregado sua lista, pode se tornar muito, mas muito, mas muito custoso para o sistema. Porque para cada `.ClienteRevendas()` e `.Empresas()` ele vai ter que ficar indo e voltando do servidor toda hora.

Existem várias maneiras de como carregar, você pode dar um `Include` ou fazer o `Linq` pra trazer uma consulta mais enxuta tbm...

Nesse [link](http://ferhenriquef.com/2013/10/13/entity_framework_melhores_praticas_performance_desempenho/) tem algumas boas práticas ao se trabalhar com o Entity, dê uma olhada em especial nos Items **5,7,8** que envolvem bem aquilo que eu gostaria de passar aqui.